# Реализовать шаблонный класс со специализацией шаблонов и исключениями

Tags: c++, массивы, исключения, шаблоны-с++, операторы

Здравствуйте.

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать шаблонный класс для массива со:

- специализацией шаблонов,
- обработкой исключений,
- тестами.

В классе Array:

```
Array()
Array(const Array&)
Array(int len, const T& x = T());
operator[]
at(int)     // из-за этого оператора надо написать обработку исключений
void push_back(const T&)
T& back()
void pop()
Iterator Begin()
Iterator End()
для класса Iterator
operator ++(int)
operator ++()
operator --(int)
operator --()
operator +=
operator -=
operator =
операторы сравнения (все эти операторы работают с индексом)
operator *

// освобождение памяти
// тесты для всех операторов и для выделения/освобождения памяти
```

В классе Allocator - реализуется стратегия управления памятью.
По идее там хватит только функции reallocate. Туда надо добавить оператор получения элемента по индексу.

Тесты должны выводить "Wrong", когда всё плохо или "Оk", если всё хорошо.

Специализацию шаблона нужно сделать для типа bool:
тип bool занимает 1 байт, а должен бы занимать 1 бит. Есть темплейтный массив, когда мы в него передаём бул, нужно чтобы он занимал в 8 раз меньше памяти чем занимает. Можно хранить инты, в один инт может влезть 32 типа булеан.

Я понимаю как сделать шаблонный класс, но без специализации шаблонов и без освобождения памяти. Прошу помочь продвинуться дальше. Хотя бы примерно показать как это делается.

Пока на такой стадии:

**Array.h:**

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include "Allocator.h"

template <typename T>
class Array{
    Allocator<T> data;

    template<typename T>
    class ArrayIterator{
        const Array<T>& array;
        unsigned position;

        void moveIt(int shift){
            if ((shift > 0 && position == AFTER_END) || (position != AFTER_END && position + shift > array.size())
                || (shift < 0 && (position!=AFTER_END ? position : array.size()+1)-shift < 0))
                throw IteratorException();
            if (position == AFTER_END && shift < 0)
                position = array.size() - abs(shift);
            else if (position + shift == array.size())
                position = AFTER_END;
            else
                position += shift;
        }
    public:

        ArrayIterator(const Array<T>& array, unsigned position){...}

        ArrayIterator(const ArrayIterator<T>& it){...}

        const T& operator*() const{
            return array[position];
        }

        ArrayIterator<T> operator++(int){
            ArrayIterator lastState(*this);
            moveIt(+1);
            return lastState;
        }

        ArrayIterator<T>& operator++(){
            moveIt(+1);
            return *this;
        }

        ArrayIterator<T> operator--(int){
            ArrayIterator lastState(*this);
            moveIt(-1);
            return lastState;
        }

        ArrayIterator<T>& operator--(){
            moveIt(-1);
            return *this;
        }

        ArrayIterator<T>& operator+=(int value){
            moveIt(value);
            return *this;
        }

        ArrayIterator<T>& operator-=(int value){
            moveIt(-value);
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const ArrayIterator<T>& it) const{
            return &array == &it.array && position == it.position;
        }

        bool operator!=(const ArrayIterator<T>& it) const{
            return !((*this) == it);
        }

        bool operator>(const ArrayIterator<T>& it) const{
            return &array == &it.array && postion > it.position;
        }

        bool operator>=(const ArrayIterator<T>& it) const{
            return (*this) > it || (*this) == it;
        }

        bool operator<(const ArrayIterator<T>& it) const{
            return &array == &it.array && postion < it.position;
        }

        bool operator<=(const ArrayIterator<T>& it) const{
            eturn(*this) < it || (*this) == it;
        }
    };

public:
    Array(unsigned len, const T& x = T()){...}

    Array(const Array& arr){...}

    Array(const T array [], unsigned size){
        ...
    }

    const T& operator[](unsigned index) const{
        ...
    }

    const T& at(unsigned index) const{
        return (*this)[index];
    }

    T& operator[](unsigned index){
        ...
    }

    void push_back(const T& item){
        (*this)[data.incrementSize()] = item;
    }

    const T& back() const{
        return (*this)[size() - 1];
    }

    void pop(){
        ...
    }

    const ArrayIterator<T> begin() const{
        ...
    }

    const ArrayIterator<T> end() const{
        ...
    }

    unsigned size() const{
        return data.getSize();
    }

    class IndexException{};
    class ArrayIsEmpty{};
    class IteratorException{};
};

#endif
```

**Allocator.h:**

```
#ifndef ALLOCATOR_H
#define ALLOCATOR_H

template <typename T>
class Allocator{
    unsigned size;
    unsigned allow;
    double FACTOR = 1.5;
    T* data;
public:
    Allocator(unsigned size){
        this->size = size;
        allow = size * FACTOR;
        data = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * allow);
    }

    Allocator(unsigned size, const T& defaultValue){
        this->size = size;
        allow = (int) (size * FACTOR);
        data = (T*) malloc(sizeof(T) * allow);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            data[i] = defaultValue;
    }

    Allocator(const Allocator<T>& alloc){
        size = alloc.size;
        allow = alloc.allow;
        data = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * allow);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            data[i] = alloc.data[i];
    }

    unsigned getSize() const{
        return size;
    }

    unsigned incrementSize(unsigned increment = 1){
        unsigned oldSize = size;
        size += increment;
        if (allow <= size)
            reallocate((int)(allow * FACTOR));
        return oldSize;
    }

    unsigned decrementSize(unsigned decrement = 1){
        unsigned oldSize = size;
        size = (size - decrement > 0) ? size - decrement : 0;
        return oldSize;
    }

    unsigned getAllowedMemorySize() const{
        return allow;
    }

    void reallocate(unsigned newSize){
        allow = newSize;
        data = (T*)realloc(data, sizeof(T) * newSize);
    }

    const T& getItem(unsigned index) const{
        return data[index];
    }

    T& getItem(unsigned index){
        return data[index];
    }

    ~Allocator(){
        free(data);
    }

};

#endif
```

Ещё в третьем хидере Tests.h нужно реализовать тесты и **main.c** будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

#include "Array.h"
#include "Tests.h"

int main(){

    testPushPop();
    //вывод "Ok" или "Wrong"
    testSetGet();
    //вывод "Ok" или "Wrong"
    testIterator();
    //вывод "Ok" или "Wrong"
    testCopy();
    //вывод "Ok" или "Wrong"
    testExceptions();
    //вывод "Ok" или "Wrong"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Art Mart, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Скопируйте исходник `std::vector`, делов-то! :-D

Comment: Я сделал шаблонный класс и несколько тестов, но без специализации шаблонов и без освобождения памяти. Прошу помочь продвинуться дальше. Хоть примерно показать как это делается.

Comment: @Art Mart: Отлично, так у вас почти всё есть. Смотрите ответ.

Comment: @Art Mart, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу специализации, на самом деле всё очень просто. Допустим, мы делаем специализацию для `bool`, в которой будет использоваться 1 бит на значение. В дополнение к существущему коду допишите:

```
template <>
class Allocator<bool>
{
    // и тут специальная имплементация, в которой аллоцируется битовое поле
};

template <>
class Array<bool>
{
    // и тут специальная имплементация Array<bool>,
    // использующая битовое поле
};
```

Пример работы с битовым массивом всплывал на сайте много раз. Например, есть [тут](/questions/326628/). Если что-то не до конца ясно, переспрашивайте.

Если вы хотите расшарить часть кода между общим `Array<T>` и `Array<bool>`, вынесите, например, общую часть в общий базовый класс.

Освобождение памяти у вас, насколько я понимаю, и так есть: деструктор аллокатора вызывает `free(data)`.

---

P. S.: Реализация итераторов для битового массива — штука неочевидная. В частности, разыменование такого итератора не может предоставить `bool` (т. к. вы не можете сослаться «внутрь» упакованного слова). Оно должно предоставить экземпляр специальной структуры, которая

- умеет неявно cast'иться в `bool`;
- имеет оператор присваивания из `bool`
- внутри себя знает номер бита, и соответствующим образом реализует доступ к нему.

---

P. P. S.: Ваша имплементация разыменования итератора, кстати, не вполне верна: вы возвращаете `const T&`, а не `T&`, поэтому такое не получится: `*array.begin() = 0;`. Возвращайте `T&`.